# Get Layer's weights inside the call function in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

If I have an optimization algorithm that has three parameters i.e., scale, sigma, and min_size. And I need to optimize these parameters with the parameters of a deep neural net. The problem I face is that I cant access the three weights I define for a custom Keras Layer inside the call function.
As the code bellow shows, I want to access the weights I define in the call function such that I apply the optimization algorithm with the new learned parameters.
Kindly, if anyone can help?

```
class SeqmentationOptimization(tensorflow.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SeqmentationOptimization, self).__init__()
        scale_init = tensorflow.keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval=10, maxval=1000, seed=None)
        sigma_init = tensorflow.keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval=0.001, maxval=1, seed=None)
        min_size_init = tensorflow.keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval=10, maxval=1000, seed=None)


        self.scale = self.add_weight(shape=[1],
                                initializer = scale_init,
                                trainable=True)
        self.sigma = self.add_weight(shape=[1],
                                initializer = sigma_init,
                                trainable=True)
        
        self.min_size = self.add_weight(shape=[1],
                                initializer = min_size_init,
                                trainable=True)

    def call(self, inputs):
        objects = Segmentation(self.scale , self.sigma , self.min_size ).objects
        return
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is a generative process of some sort which you can measure how well a set of scale, sigma, and min_size optimizes.  If that's true, then it implies you have some sort of ground truth.  As such, the output of the dnn would be these three parameters, post which loss would be computed (you define loss function).  Then gradients would be computed and weights updated to minimize loss.  As such, my naive understanding is that you can do this with a simpler architecture using functional api.  The weights aren't your parameters, the outputs are; and you would have access to those.

Comment: You can access trainable weights of a layer/model from inside itself via `self.trainable_weights`

Comment: What do you mean you can't access them? What happens when you do? Do you get an error? If yes include it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

My codes are simple but you can access the target weights assigned or adjusted. I see your intention that to adjust the scale, sigma and min_size you can add the relationship and run optimizes. ( My previous example I do it for game such Galaxy or Image recognition )

**[ Sample ]:**

```
class Segmentation( ):
    def __init__( self, scale , sigma , min_size ):
        
        print( 'start __init__: ' )
        self.scale = scale
        self.sigma = sigma
        self.min_size = min_size
        
        scale = tf.compat.v1.get_variable('scale', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random.normal((1, 10, 1)))
        sigma = tf.compat.v1.get_variable('sigma', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random.normal((1, 10, 1)))
        min_size = tf.compat.v1.get_variable('min_size', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random.normal((1, 10, 1)))
        
        Z = tf.nn.l2_loss( ( scale - sigma ) +( scale - min_size ) , name="loss")
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=tf.square(Z))
        
        optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(
        learning_rate,
        initial_accumulator_value=0.1,
        l1_regularization_strength=0.2,
        l2_regularization_strength=0.1,
        use_locking=False,
        name='ProximalAdagrad'
        )
        training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
        
        self.loss = loss
        self.scale = scale
        self.sigma = sigma
        self.min_size = min_size
        self.training_op = training_op
        
        return 
    
    def create_loss_fn( self ):
        print( 'start create_loss_fn: ' )
        
        return self.loss, self.scale, self.sigma, self.min_size, self.training_op
    

X = np.reshape([ 500, -400, 400, -300, 300, -200, 200, -100, 100, 1 ], (1, 10, 1))
Y = np.reshape([ -400, 400, -300, 300, -200, 200, -100, 100, -50, 50 ], (1, 10, 1))
Z = np.reshape([ -100, 200, -300, 300, -400, 400, -500, 500, -50, 50 ], (1, 10, 1))


loss_segmentation = Segmentation( scale , sigma , min_size )
loss, scale, sigma, min_size, training_op = loss_segmentation.create_loss_fn( )
    
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())
    
    for i in range(1000):
        global_step = global_step + 1
        
        # train_loss, temp = sess.run([loss, training_op], feed_dict={X_var:X, y_var:Y})
        train_loss, temp = sess.run([loss, training_op], feed_dict={scale:X, sigma:Y, min_size:Z})
        history.append(train_loss)
        history_Y.append( history[0] - train_loss )
        
        print( 'steps: ' + str(i) )
        
sess.close()

plt.plot(np.asarray(history))
plt.plot(np.asarray(history_Y))
plt.show()
plt.close()

input('...')
```

**[ Output ]:**
[image: Sample]